Filmed in Deland Florida in early-mid 1990's?
My ex-in-laws were renting a big, three story yellow house on Howry Av, a couple blocks from downtown in the 90's. There was a movie filmed there about an all black group of soldiers in, I believe, the Vietnam war. The storyline was that they were all black criminals and therefore expendable in war...their group was sent out first. One man was a preacher who came home to find his wife cheating and he killed the man and his wife, was sent to prison and then sent to war with other black convicts. The church scenes were filmed at the Methodist church on Howry (I'm pretty sure...), the exterior home scenes used my in-laws house and interior scenes used their landlords house next door. I remember watching the scene where two little girls stopped jump roping when they heard gunshots, filmed right in front of my in-laws house.... I can't for the life of me remember the name of the movie!!!! It would have been like 1994ish... 
I actually saw it on tv a year or so later. I swear the title was something like 'dead men walking' or 'walking dead' but I can't seem to get past the obvious newer titles in my searching... Anybody have any insight on this one?!

It was "The Walking Dead."  You can read a description on separatecinema.com and imdb:

